# hook_form_alter not running if cache enabled

Tags: 7, forms

I have enabled the cache in Administer->Development->Performance. I have changed user profile form using `hook_form_alter`. But the code inside `hook_form_alter` strops automatically after few days. I thinks, it may be cache issue.

Everything I did in hook_form_alter is not running. I changed the submit button value. I added a custom Save and Continue button.

My Sample Code is below :

```
if($form_id == "user_profile_form" && $user->uid == 1) {
    $userid = arg(1);
    if(is_numeric($userid)) {
      drupal_set_message("Current User Id on site: ".$userid);
    }
   }
```

Attached screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: Normal cache does not affect anything seen by logged-in users, so I can't see how can it be connected. Also, 5min cache and "few days" does not look consistent. Last but not least, could you please show us your code?

Comment: I added my code sample. Please check.

Comment: are you declaring `global $user;` before running your code block mentioned?  if not, the second half of your `if` is most probably failing.  If you are declaring it, your code block will only run if it is the super user (eg uid 1) that is running it, and then the `$userid` being set isn't really the current user id on site, but rather the uid of the profile being looked at.  So, needless to say there is some confusion going on here...

Comment: @Jimajamma yes I add `global $user;` before 'if' statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing `hook_form_alter` to `hook_form_form-id_alter`.

Answer (score 1):

Messages set by `drupal_set_message()` goes thorough message router and may end up displayed on another page than the one you set them. If you want to add informative element to your form, use [*markup* Form API element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) instead.

```
if($form_id == "user_profile_form" && $user->uid == 1) {
  $userid = arg(1);
  if(is_numeric($userid)) {
    $form['info'] = array(
      '#markup' => t("Current User Id on site: !uid", array('!uid' => $userid)),
      '#weight' => -9999,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My issue is not message. Everything I did in hook_form_alter is not running. I changed the submit button value. I added a custom Save and Continue button.

Comment: @SumitMadan if your issue is not about what you post in your question, how you can expect answer relevant to your issue? Message not appearing where you expect it to is a pretty common problem and fits what you posted.